# Color Switcher using buttons

Tags: arrays, reactjs, function, button

During a React Developer interview, I was asked to make a function. I'm basically new to this and I'm supposed to be able to make this easily, but there's a catch.

Make an array of colors (as strings). Write a function to create a color manager. It should only have methods (and no properties):

● get - returns the color currently selected

● next - switch to the next color

● prev - switch back to the previous color

● reset - return to the original color

Using the function you have made, you can specify a default color. Each color manager should have its own color.

From the tutorials that I learned from, props have always been used. I'm stuck in this case, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code that you developed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, and here is one of them. Basically, I have `colorManager` function which returns an object containing all the methods that you have described. This function has one argument which is the  `defaultColor` parameter. Also, I have added `setPalette` method, in case we need more flexibility to change the list of pre-defined colors. Below you can also see usage and colsole output of the methods described.

```
function colorManager(defaultColor) {
  let stack = [defaultColor, "red", "green", "blue", "pink"];
  let index = 0;

  return {
    
    get: function () {
      return stack[index];
    },

    next: function () {
      index += 1;
      if (index >= stack.length) {
        index = 0;
      }

      return this.get();
    },

    prev: function () {
      index -= 1;
      if (index < 0) {
        index = stack.length - 1;
      }

      return this.get();
    },

    reset: function () {
      index = stack.indexOf(defaultColor);
      return this.get();
    },

    setPalette: function(colours) {
      stack = [defaultColor, ...colours]
    }
  };
}

const cm1 = colorManager("purple");

console.log(cm1.get()); // purple
console.log(cm1.next()); // red
console.log(cm1.next()); // green
console.log(cm1.prev()); // red
console.log(cm1.reset()); // purple
```

Comment: this is amazing. I had no idea you could use functions in this manner. Thanks a lot!